# Rails Devise after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models namely `user` and `technician`. I want `technicians` to be directed to a particular page when they login so I implemented it according to the devise tutorial and put this in the application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource.class
  when technician
    new_services_path  
  when user
    root_path
  end
end
```

but I get this error.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
what am I missing here?

Comment: @raj  Thanks for your help but I got this error when I implemented the suggestions  undefined method `technician_url' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fd2ccabbb10>  `  if options.empty?
            recipient.send(method, *args)
          else
            recipient.send(method, *args, options)
          end`

Comment: Cool, I got your point, however, you should follow isolation principle of SO. I feel original question has been answered. You should go ahead and accept an answer for this question. Then post another question. You can post link of new question here too so that we can help you and community better

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your `switch`. `resource.class` will return class of the resource (`User` or `Technician`). So, you modify your method as follow:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource.class
  when Technician
    new_services_path  
  when User
    root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are being written with capital letter: `Technician`, `User`. The following code should work:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource.class
  when Technician
    new_services_path  
  when User
    root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource.class.name
  when "Technician"
    new_services_path  
  when "User"
    root_path
  end
end
```